# How do I search a page for a text and click on that text containing button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Suppose there is a string 'Click me' on a website. I need to click  on that text assuming it is a link using JavaScript. I am building a chrome extension to do so. But my code is not working for all cases.

This is my code so far.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Such Activity",
    "description": "Wow", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"], 
    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icons/19.png",
            "38": "images/icons/38.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icons/16.png",
        "19": "images/icons/19.png",
        "38": "images/icons/38.png",
        "64": "images/icons/64.png",
        "128": "images/icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
function injectTheScript() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

**content_script.js**

```
function clickSome() {
    function getElementsByText(text) {
        function rec(ele, arr)
        {
            if (ele.childNodes.length > 0) 
                for (var i = 0; i < ele.childNodes.length; i++) 
                    rec(ele.childNodes[i], arr);
            else if (ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && 
                     ele.nodeValue.indexOf(text) != -1) 
                arr.push(ele.parentNode);
            return arr;
        }
        return rec(document.body, []);
    }
    var x = 'Text';
    var my = getElementsByText(x.ignoreCase);
    var mod =my[0].className;
    console.log(my);
    document.getElementsByClassName(mod)[0].click();
}
clickSome();
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>activity</title></head>  
<body>  
    <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the button uses a specific element you can look for it directly, otherwise see examples for TreeWalker API with NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT. Also, instead of tabs and all_urls permissions use [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Comment: Thank you for providing complete code. However, you are missing **►a specific problem or error **. Without specifying your exact problem we don't know what to help you with.

Comment: @Makyen The problem is that how would I go about Clicking on the text containing button using javascript.

Comment: @VishnuDev, That is not a reasonable statement of the "problem". That is a statement of your desire. You have said "But my code is not working for all cases". You need to tell us what actually happens (i.e. what "not working" means) and specify the cases which do and don't work.

Comment: If a button has two span elements inside of it and text in the last span, then the getelementsbytext function fetches the improper element rather than button element.

Comment: @Makyen If there is a button with text only then it fetches proper element and clicks on it.

Comment: @VishnuDev, Please provide example HTML of what it works with and where it fails.